# Is it possible to get a callback from google Plus Badge(Add to Circles)?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

I just made a Add to circle badge form [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/personal-config).So now i just want to detect that a user add me into their circle or not.

So is it possible to get a callback from this badge on users action just like we can get a callback from google plus one button.

If callback is not present yet then is their any good way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge does not have any callbacks at this time. If they existed they'd be documented on [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/).

For privacy reasons the badge is designed to make adding your own callbacks very difficult or impossible.

Comment: thanks for the answer.If in future you will find a method of doing this or if google people update that and you came to know.Then please post it here.I will be very thankful to you for that...:-)

Comment: oh..i just came to know(via http://mimming.com/) that,you are also a googler,so now i can say that if you people add a callback then post it here...:-)

Comment: I just figure out via firebug that whenever a user add someone into their circle or remove someone from their circle then the badge  send different kinds of request to google-plus server and in response their is  some javascript/json stuff .

Comment: Will do :) If a callback is added I'll be sure to update all of my related answers on Stack Overflow (including this one!)